# How to obtain live vertical height values using LIDAR

Tags: slam, lidar, autonomous-car

I plan to control the flying height of my drone using a LIDAR (in real-time). Therefore, I would be attaching the LIDAR to my UAV, pointing vertically downwards. However, after looking at some of the LIDAR datasets, I see that there is a wreath of information. How do I extract the vertical height from here?

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? Do you want to take the roll and tilt of the copter into account? Can you assume a flat ground underneath the copter?

Comment: No, I won't take roll and tilt into account as I am not looking for that level of precision. I am assuming a flat ground, for the reasons stated above. I understand that I'll have to careful in the presence of water, as the LIDAR will definitely get that wrong.

Comment: then where is your problem?

Comment: @FooTheBar, A standard LIDAR churns out 3D data. How do I isolate the z-axis from it?

Comment: a standard Lidar gives you distance values for different directions. You only have to select the right beam. Which sensor are you using?

Comment: You're right! The GUI from the LIDAR that I use, gives me the distance values. Thank you.